# Object detection: better to train with imbalanced dataset or remove images to balance out

Tags: unbalanced-classes, object-detection

I am training an object detection model using the YOLOv5 architecture. I have the following classes and counts.

```
| class | n_instances |
| ----- | ----------- |
| dog   | 1000        |
| cat   | 4000        |
| fox   | 8000        |
```

My training dataset is imbalanced. The difference between the largest and the smallest group is `(8000/(8000 + 1000)) - (1000/(8000 + 1000)) =`  77%. What should I do?

- **Option 1**: Just ignore it and train the model with this imbalanced dataset.
- **Option 2**: Balance the dataset by removing 7000 foxes, 3000 cats and train the model with a balanced dataset of 1000 instances of each class.

I can imagine that option 2 is better suited for *very* imbalanced datasets, and option 1 for only *slightly* imbalanced datasets. If this is true, what would define '*very*' and '*slightly*'? In other words, at which percentage would be the threshold?